# Windows Mobile 6.5 Process.Start

Tags: c#, compact-framework

I have a GUI application which starts two command line applications ( no window, just processes ) on Windows Mobile 6.5. I am using following code to start process:

```
Process service = new Process();
var pi = new ProcessStartInfo(exePath, null);
    pi.UseShellExecute = false;        
    service.StartInfo = pi;
    //start the process
    service.Start();
```

Everything works fine, except, when service.Start() is called, my GUI application is covered by a circle thingy rotating in the center of the screen. Same Icon that rotates while waiting for a program to start, means OS is busy. Now since these processes will run for the life time of the GUI and even after GUI will quit, this circle does not go away. Is there a way to make it go away, via code? i tried Invalidating gui to repaint and changing cursor to normal. Dosnt work?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

**What does `exePath` launch?**

My guess is that [Simon McKenzie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622391/simon-mckenzie) has already nailed this one on the head. That is probably exactly what is going on.

However, the OS will also throw up a [WaitCursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursors.waitcursor.aspx) (the *circle thingy rotating in the center of the screen*) whenever it starts up some intensive CPU process. If that is the case, you may want to rethink how to approach this process you are launching - particularly if you are the one who wrote the process.

Consider the hypothetical application below to poll the network and compiled to your `exePath`:

```
while (true) {
  if (networkDataAvailable()) {
    processData();
  }
}
```

That hypothetical application would be eating away at the processor's idle time.

If the process you are launching does something like that, you'll need to find another way to approach the problem like calling a simpler process in a timer tick event.

The modified process identified by the `exePath` would now be:

```
if (networkDataAvailable()) {
  processData();
}
```

And from your Windows application, you could call this as needed like so:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Process service = new Process();
  var pi = new ProcessStartInfo(exePath, null);
  pi.UseShellExecute = false;        
  service.StartInfo = pi;
  //start the process
  service.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the call to `service.Start()` may be blocking the main thread. Perhaps you could try starting your process in a new thread:

```
 private void StartProcess()
{
    Process service = new Process();
    var pi = new ProcessStartInfo(exePath, null);
    pi.UseShellExecute = false;        
    service.StartInfo = pi;
    //start the process
    service.Start();
}

...

Thread t = new Thread(StartProcess);
t.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult to diagnose without understanding more about what the process you are starting up in exePath is doing. If that process throws up a wait cursor and monopolizes the CPU it may explain the behaviour you are seeing.